# vim github colorscheme notworking with zsh

Tags: vim, zsh, tmux

I am using ubuntu 13.04 with the following configurations

tmux
   vim - github colorscheme
   zsh - default shell

myproblem is when i tried to open a code in vim without tmux it looks fine see below

[image]

but when i use tmux it is breaking the code like below

[image]

am i missing something or do  i need to provide anything?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by `it is breaking the code`? the long line in your 2nd screenshot (line 7) ?

Comment: yes the long line after the line 7

Comment: Vim settings? Tmux settings? Local tmux or distant tmux?

Comment: I've experienced similar problems through Tmux. Would love to see a fix.

Comment: Did you try `:set nowrap` to see if it make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. This has worked for me:

Add the following to the file

## `$ ~/.tmux.conf`

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Comment: Didn't work for me :/